# Retrieving a property from an action value in Angular 9 & NgRx reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm having trouble retrieving the property of a value in an NgRx reducer. I'm trying to extract the **accessToken** of the user object and store it in the state. However, despite the user object being valid and containing a valid accessToken, when I try to retrieve the accessToken it returns undefined.

In the debugger if I hover over the user object, I can see the full value with all the properties including accessToken, but if I skip to the next line and hover over accessToken object it shows undefined.

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
import { AuthActions } from '../action-types';

export const authFeatureKey = 'auth';

export interface AuthState {
  user: User;
  accessToken: string;
}

export const initialAuthState: AuthState = {
  user: undefined,
  accessToken: undefined,
};

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialAuthState,

  on(AuthActions.signup, (state, action) => {
    return {
      user: action.user,
      accessToken: action.user.accessToken,
    };
  }),

  on(AuthActions.signin, (state, action) => {
    // split out to debug.
    const user = <User>action.user; // action.user returns a valid object
    const token = user.accessToken; // despite this being valid in the user object, returns undefined.
    return {
      user: action.user,
      accessToken: token,
    };
  }),

  on(AuthActions.signOut, () => {
    return {
      user: undefined,
      accessToken: undefined,
    };
  }),
);

export function authReducer(state, action) {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

These are the actions:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';

export const signup = createAction('[SignUp Page] User SignUp', props<{ user: User }>());

export const signin = createAction('[SignIn Page] User SignIn', props<{ user: User }>());

export const signOut = createAction('[Top Menu] User SignOut');
```

and these are the selectors:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromAuth from './reducers';

export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<fromAuth.AuthState>(fromAuth.authFeatureKey);

export const isLoggedIn = createSelector(selectAuthState, (auth) => !!auth.user);

export const isLoggedOut = createSelector(isLoggedIn, (loggedIn) => !loggedIn);

export const getCurrentUser = createSelector(selectAuthState, (auth) => auth.user);

export const getAccessToken = createSelector(selectAuthState, (auth) => auth.accessToken);
```

This is the auth.module.ts, showing the import of the authReducer (as requested)

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import * as fromAuth from './store/reducers';
import { AuthEffects } from './store/auth-effects';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromAuth.authFeatureKey, fromAuth.authReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects]),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule,
      providers: [AuthService],
    };
  }
}
```

I have noticed that in the state, it's storing the value somewhat weirdly:

```
auth
    user
      user
         userName: "username1"
         email: "email@email.com"
         accessToken: "ey......7z"
         refreshToken: "xxx"
```

So it looks like it's somehow nesting the user object.

Comment: Why do you need to case `action.user` to type User? What is the runtime value of `action` or `action.user`?

Comment: I wouldn't normally, just in there as I'm trying to work out why I can't get the accessToken. The code would normally match the signup code above.

Comment: Could you show how `authFeatureKey` looks like, as well as how do you provide the `authReducer` to your `StoreModule` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my mistake, the service was passing the result back as a User object:

```
  signin(credentials: SignInCredentials): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>('/api/signin', credentials);
  }
```

However, it was actually the user inside an object:

```
{
   user: {
      userName:
      ...
   }
}
```

This is where it all went wrong. So I changed the service to return an any:

```
  signin(credentials: SignInCredentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<User>('/api/signin', credentials);
  }
```

and changed the action dispatch:

```
this.authService
  .signin(this.credentials)
  .pipe(
    tap((data: any) => {
      this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.signin({ user: data.user }));
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    }),
```

Feeling like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

The `action.user` can be valid, it doesn't mean it contains all required information. Especially when httpClient is used and its response is casted to any type.

You need to debug the effect that emits `AuthActions.signin` to ensure that the user it generates contains `.accessToken` value.

Comment: When I debug through the code, I can see that it does have the accessToken and all the other properties.

Comment: how do you check that it's undefined after the reducer? Might you add selectors to the question too? And how you dispatch the action.